# Customs binding cross views in mvvmcross

Tags: xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I need a custom binding and I know when and where but I don't know how I can do it. This is the relation of the view in my custom binding. Think about the *Views like controls.
[image]

I have the connections from ViewModel->ContainerView->FirstView but I can't connect it with the TableView. To connect the ContainerView to FirstView I did a custom binding (in one direction for now). And in the setvalue method I call the firstview's method SetBinding (where I want to do the binding)

I tried a few option but nothing happens, the last one looks like this:

```
public GolferList CurrentGolferList { get; set; }
    public void SetBinding(GolferList golferList){
        this.CurrentGolferList = golferList;

        TableSource = new TableSourcePlayers(TableViewPlayers);
        var bindingDescription = new[]{
            new MvxBindingDescription {TargetName = "ItemsSource",SourcePropertyPath = "CurrentGolferList"} ,
        };

        Binder.Bind(this,TableSource, bindingDescription);

        TableViewPlayers.Source = TableSource;
        TableViewPlayers.ReloadData();

    }
```

I would be grateful if you could tell me another way to handle it.

**Update**: 
I followed Stuart's link and now it works fine, thanks a lot Stuart! 
Actually, in my scheme the TableView is a MvxSimpleBindableTableViewSource and I want to bind the data there. So in order to make it work, I used the code below (SetBinding needs some external refactor):

```
    private List<IMvxUpdateableBinding> bindings;
    private string BindingText = "{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'CurrentGolfers'}}";
   public object DataContext { 
        get { return dataContext; }
        set { dataContext = value;
            if (bindings == null)
                bindings = this.GetService<IMvxBinder>().Bind(dataContext, TableSource, BindingText).ToList();
            else
                bindings.ForEach(b => b.DataContext = dataContext);
           }
        }
    public void SetBinding(GolferList golferList){
        this.DataContext = PlayViewModel;
        tableView.Source = TableSource;
        tableView.ReloadData();
   }
```

Note that BindingText points to the table, not to the view itself.

**Update 2**
Now in V3 it's a bit different. First, the view must implement IMvxBindable and this members:

```
    public object DataContext
    {
        get { return BindingContext.DataContext; }
        set { BindingContext.DataContext = value; }
    }

    public IMvxBindingContext BindingContext { get; set; }
```

(Don't forget dispose calling BindingContext.ClearAllBindings() and also call to CreateBindingContext() in the viewload )

And then you'll be able to bind in your class. In my case:

```
    var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstPlayViewController, PlayViewModel>();
    set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.CurrentGolfers).Apply(); //I love the new fluent api :)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is actual a data-bound View, rather than a custom binding.

This is covered in this question - [Custom bindable control in a MvvmCross Touch project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073262/custom-bindable-control-in-a-mvvmcross-touch-project)

Basically what you need to do is to add a collection of 'Bindings' and the 'DataContext' property to your `FirstView`.

If you do that then you should be able to databind (to DataContext) within FirstView just like you do within any normal MvvmCross view.

Note - this will be much easier to do in v3 as we've added a 'BindingContext' object to assist with exactly this type of operation